# Optimization of multivariable function In Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a function fun(x,y,z), such that say, x=1:10, y=50:60, z=100:105. Which optimization method (and how) I can use to get the minimum of this function, for example, where (x,y,z)=(3,52,101). I am working in Matlab.

Thank you for any help

Comment: The first google result for your title is [`fminsearch`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminsearch.html), try that.

Comment: I've already seen fminsearch but don't know how to use it now that my search space is discrete points (I have them) and I have 3 variables. How can I make fminsearch to choose from these given points?

Comment: I have a Combinatorial optimization problem.

Comment: Given your search space is quite small, evaluating `fun` at all grid points and then using `min` should be fine.

Comment: This is just an example. My search space is too big. That's why I am looking for a optimization method.

Comment: Well then assuming your `fun` is smooth enough, do non-integer optimisation and then look at the surrounding integer points to the minimum, that should give you the minimum (assuming your function is smooth enough). Anything more sophisticated than that is probably outside the scope of a SO answer.

Comment: Perhaps [`intlinprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) in the Optimization toolbox for R2014a+, but I can't say much else as your question isn't very detailed. Before that there is the more limited [`bintprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013b/optim/ug/bintprog.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Algorithms

There are many many algorithms out there that you can use for direct search optimization such as Nelder-Mead, Particle Swarm, Genetic Algorithm, etc.

1. I believe Nelder-Mead is a simplex optimization method which is used by [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) function in MATLAB.
2. Also, there is [Genetic Algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm.html) which comes with MATLAB Global Optimization toolbox. You may want to give that a try as well.
3. Particle Swarm Optimization (PSO) is another direct search method that you can use. However, there is no official toolbox for Particle Swarm method built by Mathworks. The good news is there is quite a few PSO toolbox developed by other people. I personally have used [this one](https://code.google.com/p/psomatlab/) and am quite happy with the performance. Its syntax is similar to Genetic Algorithm functions that come with Global Optimization Toolbox.

## Discrete Optimization

Regarding your question that you are looking for a set of integer values namely x,y, and z corresponding to the minimum objective function value, I would add a part at the beginning of the objective function that rounds the variables to the closest integers and then feeds them to your main function `fun(x,y,z)`. This way you would discretize your function space.

I hope my answer helps.